Is buying a phone with monthly instalment haram?
I'm intending to buy a phone by monthly instalment, but not sure if its halal or not?
Details about the credit:
•   APR including taxes: 0%. (interest 0%).
•   No application fees.
•   Monthly insurance fees including taxes: under 60 years old 0.077%, under 75 years old 0.11%, under 78 years old 0.143%.
My main concern is the monthly insurance fees and the fact that even though the phone is from Samsung the credit will be processed by another Company.
